# Sequelize V5 - BOOLEAN data type not supported when creating a Model

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I'm recently installed `"sequelize": "^5.21.3"` to my new node project. Also i'm using "sequelize-auto-migrations" to sync the database.(https://www.npmjs.com/package/sequelize-auto-migrations)

Then I create my first Model [User] with boolean type fields.

```
module.exports = function (sequelize, DataTypes) {
    var User = sequelize.define('user', {
        EpfNo: {
            type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
            autoIncrement: false,
            allowNull: false,
            primaryKey: true
        },
        Title: {
            type: Sequelize.STRING(10)
        },
        EmailAddress: {
            type: Sequelize.STRING(100)
        },
        ContactNo: {
            type: Sequelize.STRING(20)
        },
        IsValidUser:{
            type:Sequelize.BOOLEAN
        },
        IsActive: {
            type:Sequelize.BOOLEAN
        }
    })
```

But when I trying to run the migration, it shows the below error message.

> [#0] execute: createTable
>   (node:16296) [SEQUELIZE0004] DeprecationWarning: A boolean value was passed to options.operatorsAliases. This is a no-op with
>   v5 and should be removed.

Please help!

Comment: Does this answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59837714/6463558?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to pass "operatorsAliases" as false in you sequelize connection, like below -

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize')
const sequelize = new Sequelize(
  DB_NAME,
  USERNAME, 
  PASSWORD,
  {
    host: HOSTNAME,
    dialect: 'mysql',
    logging: false,
    freezeTableName: true,
    operatorsAliases: false
  }
)
```

Also as per you code -

```
module.exports = function (sequelize, DataTypes) {
```

you have used small latter sequelize but in filed definition you have used 
capital

```
type:Sequelize.BOOLEAN
```

Hop this helps.